# Does Ubuntu support ibmvfc?

Tags: kernel

Does 14.04 support ibmvfc modules for loading to a system with virtual fiber channel, previous versions only had ibmvscsi support.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used ibmvfc, so I can't state explicitly whether it works or not.
However, I can say that there is an ibmvfc module enabled in 14.04's ppc64 builds, as seen here:

```
$ lsb_release -sc; uname -m; uname -r
trusty
ppc64
3.13.0-24-powerpc64-smp

$ dpkg-query -S /boot/vmlinu?-$(uname -r)
linux-image-3.13.0-24-powerpc64-smp: /boot/vmlinux-3.13.0-24-powerpc64-smp

$ sudo modprobe ibmvfc
$ lsmod | grep vfc
ibmvfc                 83360  0
scsi_transport_fc      80588  1 ibmvfc

$ dmesg | tail -n 1
[  110.720647] ibmvfc: IBM Virtual Fibre Channel Driver version: 1.0.11 (April 12, 2013)
```

The module is also available for ppc64 little endian, but it is delivered in the 'linux-image-extra' package rather than linux-image.  So on ppc64el, you'll need to:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

That will get you the correct linux-image-extra-KERNEL_VERSION package.

From there, the kernel module loads, but I have no experience to test it.
If you find bugs in the ibmvfc driver, please file them on launchpad using `ubuntu-bug linux-image-generic`.